# vert.x There is a query still being run here - race -> false issue for SQLConnection

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I am using vert.x SQLConnection for database connection. where I am running simple query in loop using same connection. Following is my code sample

```
 public static void test(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.currentContext().owner();
        JsonObject configJson = new JsonObject().put("host", "mymysqldb.mycompany");
        io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.AsyncSQLClient client = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, configJson);
        client.getConnection(connectionHandler -> {
            if (connectionHandler.succeeded()) {
                SQLConnection connection = connectionHandler.result();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("count" + i);
                    try {
                        connection.query("select 1", selectHandler -> {
                            System.out.println("executed query");
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Error in get connection : ", connectionHandler.cause());
            }
        });
    }
```

but when I run this it gives me following output

```
count0
count1
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count2
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count3
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count4
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count5
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count6
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count7
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
count8
count9
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.ConnectionStillRunningQueryException: [2] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
executed query
executed query
```

I guess this can be because of it runs query asynchronously in for loop and as same connection is used again and again, it tries to execute 2nd query with same connection while first one is still running.

Well this problem will be solved if I call getDatabaseConnection method in for loop itself so that each query can use different connection. (again this can be a problem if loop is of thousand then that many connections will be created but lets ignore this problem for now). But what If I want to use transaction here, then I must need single connection to be created to be in transaction?
Is there any issue with vert.x or in my understanding. Can anyone help me how I can I achieve this

Comment: If you have this project in a GitHub repo I could have a look. It has to do with the appropriate time to close the connection and also, waiting that the query handler completes.